# agregar estilos para los archivos PDF que se descargan por JQUERY DATATABLES

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, pdf

tengo un problema al generar un archivo PDF con la libreria `Jquery Datatable`, al generar el pdf me descarga por defecto el color azul en la cabecera de la tabla, pero mi empresa maneja el color rojo, les dejo el codigo `javascript` con el que genero la descargar del PDF

```
      var table = $("#data_list_consecutivos").DataTable({
            ordering: true
        });

        new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons( table, {
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    text: 'Abrir en PDF',
                    download: 'open',
                    className: 'btn-danger',
                    messageTop: 'Pedidos de Concentrados Tramitados',
                    title:'Intranet  Cercafe',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                    },
                    customize:function(doc) {
                        doc.styles.title = {
                            color: 'red',
                            fontSize: '40',
                            alignment: 'center'
                        }
                        doc.styles['td:nth-child(2)'] = { 
                            width: '100px',
                            'max-width': '100px'
                        }
                    }
                },
            ],
        });

        table.buttons( 0, null ).container().appendTo(
            table.table().container()
        );
```

al dejarlo asi como esta me genera este PDF [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando le agrego esta linea de codigo en `javascript` me genera esto

```
                        doc.styles.tableHeader = {
                            background: '#DF0101',
                            color:'white'
                        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

les agradeceria que me ayudaran con esto

Answer (score 0):

Es porque le pones background y esa no es la propiedad a ocupar, tu codigo debe ser asi:

```
doc.styles.tableHeader = {
  fillColor:'#DF0101',
  color:'white'
}
```

Usando fillColor se resuelve, saludos.